# What is the relation between a regular language, $L$, and $\Sigma^*$?

Tags: formal-languages

Let's say I have $\Sigma = \{0\}$.

Can a language $L$ be as large as $\Sigma^*$? So $L = \Sigma^*$.

Can a language $L$ be as small as just $\{0\}$? A subset of $\Sigma^*$.

Can multiple languages, $L_1, L_2$, come from the same $\Sigma$, i.e. be subsets of the same $\Sigma^*$?

Comment: Did you read the answers to your former question(s)? Is $\epsilon$ a symbol or the empty word for you?

Comment: Also, what have you tried and where did you get stuck? It seems you are posting several questions from an exercise sheet; don't do that.

Comment: You need to review the basic definitions. Check what a language *is*. Check what an alphabet is. Also, your title asks about regular languages but the question only refers to languages. Which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A language is any set of finite strings on a given alphabet.
$\Sigma^*$ is the set of all finite strings on the alphabet
$\Sigma$. Hence ...

> Hence $\Sigma^*$ is a language on the alphabet $\Sigma$.

The set $\{0\}$ contain only strings on the alphabet
$\Sigma$. Hence ...

> Hence $\{0\}$ is a language on the alphabet $\Sigma$.

But it is not the smallest language on  the alphabet $\Sigma$.

For example $\{000000000000\}$ and $\{\epsilon\}$ are other languages
on  the alphabet $\Sigma$ that contain a single string.

And there is a smaller one: the empty language $\emptyset$ is the
smallest language on the alphabet $\Sigma$, and contans no string.

But the union of two languages on the alphabet $\Sigma$ is a language
on this alphabet, so taking for example the union of the above:
$\{000000000000,\epsilon,0\}$.

So, if my count is right, we have 6 different languages from
alphabet $\Sigma$, thus all subsets of $\Sigma^*$,
which should answer your
last question.

Comment: Ah I've been saying "The language over $\Sigma^*$..." this whole time. I should've been saying "The language over $\Sigma$..." instead. The highlighted parts really cleared up some misunderstandings. Also, pointing out my mistake on the smallest language. Thank you.